# Get specific property from all items from the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have list of Contacts:

```
public class Contact
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private int _age;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fname">Contact's First Name</param>
    /// <param name="lname">Contact's Last Name</param>
    /// <param name="age">Contact's Age</param>
    public Contact(string fname, string lname, int age)
    {
        _firstName = fname;
        _lastName = lname;
        _age = age;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contact Last Name
    /// </summary>
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contact First Name
    /// </summary>
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
           return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contact Age
    /// </summary>
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return _age;
        }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and here I am creating my list:

```
private List<Contact> _contactList;
_contactList = new List<Contact>();
_contactList.Add(new Contact("John", "Jackson", 45));
_contactList.Add(new Contact("Jack", "Doe", 20));
_contactList.Add(new Contact("Jassy", "Dol", 19));
_contactList.Add(new Contact("Sam", "Josin", 44));
```

Right now I am trying to get all the first names of all the contacts in separate list using LINQ.

So far I tried:

```
    public List<string> FirstNames
    {
        get
        {
           return _contactList.Where(C => C.FirstName.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note for your accessors in your class, you can simply type `public int Age {get; set; }` all on one line instead of what you have since you're not performing any other actions in the accessor. It's, obviously, much shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Where is for evaluating a Select condition like: foreach contact where (firstname starts with "J") select (contact)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You want to use the `Select` method, not `Where` here:

```
_contactList.Select(C => C.FirstName).ToList();
```

Further, the need for the `ToList()` only exists because the `property` demands it. You could return an `IEnumerable<string>` instead if you wanted to get rid of that.

Comment: @Stanislav, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: What if **FirstName** is dynamic, may come from parameter as string?

Comment: @ibubi if `FirstName` is dynamic then you'd want to cast that inside the `Select` expression.

Answer (score 7):

```
public List<string> FirstNames
{
    get
    {
       return _contactList.Select(C => C.FirstName).ToList();
    }
}
```