# Get an object from multiple List<T> lists with a specific id

Tags: c#, list, generics

In `C#`, if I have multiple `List<T>` lists, where each item in the list inherits from an interface that has an `id` property, how is the best way to retrieve an object that has a specific `id`?

All `ids` are unique and all lists are stored in one object.

I am currently thinking of writing a `Find` piece of code, for each list, and if the object returned is not null, then the object returned is the object with the id.

Is there a better way to do this?

Just to inform, this question is about how to find an object in multiple lists, rather than the code to find an object in a single list.

Comment: Can you switch from List<T> to Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, where TKey is the type of the id field and TValue is of T? This way you can find the object by its id.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered MANY times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937060/how-to-check-if-listt-element-contains-an-item-with-a-particular-property-valu or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962862/get-specific-property-from-all-items-from-the-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of lists, and search it using LINQ's `SelectMany`:

Here is an example setup:

```
interface IId {
    int Id {get;}
}
class A : IId {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return "A"+Id;
    }
}
class B : IId {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return "B"+Id;
    }
}
```

`IId` is the common interface implemented by `A` and `B`. Now you can do this:

```
var a = new List<A> {new A {Id=5}, new A {Id=6}};
var b = new List<B> {new B {Id=7}, new B {Id=8}};
var all = new List<IEnumerable<IId>> {a, b};
```

`all` is a list that contains lists of different subtypes of `IId`. It needs to be declared as list of `IEnumerable`s because of covariance rules for generics.

Now you can search `all` by `Id`, like this:

```
var item5 = all.SelectMany(list => list).FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == 5);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BvfUfr)

Answer (score 3):

How about using Linq:

```
var result = list.First(x => x.id == findThisId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result =
 new [] { list1, list2, list3, ... }
 .Select(list => list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == findThisId))
 .First(x => x != null);
```

You also could treat the multiple lists as one concatenated list:

```
var result =
 new [] { list1, list2, list3, ... }
 .SelectMany(x => x) //flatten
 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == findThisId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```